# Mongodb GridFS read return empty content

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

When I was using mongodb's python api mongoengine, to read file from GridFS, I got empty content after the first read.
Here is what I've tried:

```
class Test(Document):
    file=FileField()
a = Test(id=id)
print a.file.read() # has expected output
print a.file.read() # empty
print a.file.read() # empty`
```

So I'm curious about how does GridFS read works, thanks in advance for any hints :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll have to improve the corresponding [documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/gridfs.html#retrieval) as it's a common source of confusion but you need to "rewind" the stream once you've read it.

I.e:

```
class Test(Document):
    file = FileField()

a = Test(id=id)
print a.file.read() # has expected output

a.file.seek(0)

print a.file.read()
```

Note that this isn't specific to MongoEngine but it's how the underlying GridFS/GridOut file-like object behave